# Changing opacity color of image

Tags: css, nativescript

So this is the snippet of my code:

```
<GridLayout>
    <NavigationButton visibility="hidden"></NavigationButton>
    <Label class="fas p-10 h2 nav-button" text="&#xf0c9;" (tap)="onDrawerButtonTap()"></Label>
    <Image src="res://img1" stretch="aspectFill" class="top-img"> </Image>
    <StackLayout class="section-1">
        <Label text="Frequently Asked Questions" textWrap="true" class="h1 title"></Label>
        <Label text="Date Today" textWrap="true" class="h2 date"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

and its CSS:

```
.top-img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I want to change the opacity color of the `Image` to red but I think it doesn't work on Nativescript. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of filter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of the image, try to use `filter` instead of `opacity`. First, convert your image to grayscale, then adjust the other values to find the color you want.

In the example below I played around with the filters to show the image in red.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}

.top-img {
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(50%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-50deg) saturate(600%) contrast(0.8);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" class="top-img" />
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" />
```